# Can I override default css class from a library?

Tags: css

In an MWF (for company employees only) library. I see a class="x-hidden-focus" which disable visible focus when press Tab. Can I override it with other CSS?

Comment: If you can provide more details like CSS/HTML and the line of code in question, it will help in answering more precisely. 

[Questions seeking code help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

You can override CSS using `parent` child relation or by adding new `class selector` or `id` or finally using `!important`.

I would suggest you to use `parent` class to override the CSS of the child. In case if you are using `!important` you need to take care its not breaking CSS anywhere else in the application.